# How To Compare Months/Days in Kotlin Exposed?

Tags: sql-server, kotlin-exposed

I am trying to query for events in SQL Server that are within a time frame but discarding the year because I am looking for yearly events. I'm trying to build a query by comparing months and month days to a their integer equivalents, but there doesn't seem to be a way to.

With column types of `Column<DateTime>`, you can compare with `lessEq`/`greaterEq`. However, if I simply want to compare months, using `columnDate.month()` returns an `Expression` and is not of type `Column`, and there aren't any `lessEq`/`greaterEq` equivalents.

Another issue is that there's not even a `monthDay` extension function. Luckily, that's easier to manage since it would be the same as the month function with a tiny alteration:

```
fun <T: DateTime?> Expression<T>.monthDay() = DayOfMonth(this)

class DayOfMonth<T:DateTime?>(val expr: Expression<T>): Function<Int>(IntegerColumnType()) {
        override fun toQueryBuilder(queryBuilder: QueryBuilder) = queryBuilder { append("DAY(", expr,")") }
}
```

The goal for me is too ultimately have an expression like `TableName.dateColumnName.betweenIgnoreYear(startDate, endDate)` return an `Op<Boolean>`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not sure that the sql server tag is relevant here. I get that is where you store your data but seems like this question is not about how to use sql server to get the data.

Comment: I put the tag on here since Kotlin Exposed covers multiple database dialects, and the solution may end up being SQL Server specific.

Answer (score 1):

UPD: There are month/days/etc functions in Exposed since 0.19.1

You were just a halfway to the right code:

```
class BetweenIgnoreYear<T:DateTime?>(
     val expr: Expression<T>, 
     val from: Expression<T>, 
     val to: Expression<T>) : Op<Boolean>() 
{
    override fun toQueryBuilder(queryBuilder: QueryBuilder) = queryBuilder {
        append(expr.monthDay(), " BETWEEN ", from.monthDay(), " AND ", to.monthDay())
    }
}


fun <T: DateTime?> Expression<T>.betweenIgnoreYear(startDate : Expression<T>, endDate : Expression<T>) 
    = BetweenIgnoreYear(this, startDate, endDate)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, as I was trying to work the logic out yesterday, I realized that ignoring the year would lead to a big problem if my between dates rolled the year over (ex. the start date is in December and the end date is in January) and I don't think there's an easy, solution that wouldn't make the query take a while. But while you're here, I wanted to mention that the regular between function has trouble converting `DateTime`s for some reason. I end up having to convert it to a string with the pattern "MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss:SSS".

Comment: Also, even if I could use this class, I'm unsure on how to create the extension function for it correctly because I don't know how to access `SqlExpressionBuilder`'s `asLiteral` function.

Comment: @JCamacho, could you file an issue with DateTime conversion bug at https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/ 
 val literal = with(SqlExpressionBuilder) {  OrdersTable.date.asLiteral(DateTime.now()) }